# How to apply org-todo to multiple items

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Consider an emacs org-mode file like this:

```
** item 1
** item 2
** item 3
** item 4
```

Now I can apply `org-todo` to every item separately (bound to `C-c C-t`). But how can I apply it to every item in region at once? Just selecting the region and doing it doesnt't work, it just adds the TODO keyword to the item below the region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished with [Emacs Rectangles](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Rectangles.html)' `string-rectangle` function.

```
M-x string-rectangle
```

---

### Here's An Example:

*Update: My example is for 3 items.*

Select the region starting just after the first `**`  to just before `item 3` (See pic).

[image: Before]

Then type `C-x r t`

```
String rectangle (default TODO):
```

Press `RET` if the default is `TODO` otherwise type `TODO` and then `RET`.

[image: After]

Comment: This is a great solution if there are no sub-headings, but if the items have sub-headings, it will add TODO for those too, which may not be desirable.

Answer (score 0):

[Macros!](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyboardMacros)

Use `F3` to start recording the macro, do a `C-c C-t` on one line followed by the down arrow then press `F4`.

After that do `C-u 10 C-x e`, for example if you had to repeat it 10 times or just press `F4` how many ever times you need to mark TODO.